# Grunt: Css file not minimizing

Tags: javascript, css, gruntjs

The issue is I am not able to minimise the .css files into a dist folder.
I am getting the following error, when I run the command 'grunt'. Help me. Thanks in advance.

```
Running "concat:dist" (concat) task

Running "cssmin:dist" (cssmin) task
>> No files created.

Running "uglify:dist" (uglify) task
>> No files created.

Running "copy:dist" (copy) task


Running "copy:fonts" (copy) task
```

My HTML file head and the code for Grunt.js is as follows:

```js
'use strict';

module.exports = function (grunt) {
  // Define the configuration for all the tasks
     // Time how long tasks take. Can help when optimizing build times
   require('time-grunt')(grunt);

   // Automatically load required Grunt tasks
   require('jit-grunt')(grunt, {
     useminPrepare: 'grunt-usemin'
   }); 
   // Define the configuration for all the tasks
   grunt.initConfig({
     pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

     // Make sure code styles are up to par and there are no obvious mistakes
     jshint: {
       options: {
         jshintrc: '.jshintrc',
         reporter: require('jshint-stylish')
       },
       
       all: {
         src: [
           'Gruntfile.js',
           'app/scripts/{,*/}*.js'
         ]
       }
     },
     copy: {
       dist: {
         cwd: 'app',
         src: [ '**','!styles/**/*.css','!scripts/**/*.js' ],
         dest: 'dist',
         expand: true
       },
       
       fonts: {
         files: [
           {
             //for bootstrap fonts
             expand: true,
             dot: true,
             cwd: 'bower_components/bootstrap/dist',
             src: ['fonts/*.*'],
             dest: 'dist'
           }, {
             //for font-awesome
             expand: true,
             dot: true,
             cwd: 'bower_components/font-awesome',
             src: ['fonts/*.*'],
             dest: 'dist'
           }
         ]
       }
     },

     clean: {
       build: {
         src: [ 'dist/']
       }
   },


   useminPrepare: {
     html: 'app/detail.html',
     options: {
       dest: 'dist'
     }
   },

   // Concat
   concat: {
     options: {
       separator: ';'
     },
     
     // dist configuration is provided by useminPrepare
     dist: {}
   },

   // Uglify
   uglify: {
     // dist configuration is provided by useminPrepare
     dist: {}
   },

   cssmin: {
     dist: {}
   },

   // Filerev
   filerev: {
     options: {
       encoding: 'utf8',
       algorithm: 'md5',
       length: 20
     },
     
     release: {
       // filerev:release hashes(md5) all assets (images, js and css )
       // in dist directory
       files: [{
         src: [
           'dist/scripts/*.js',
           'dist/styles/*.css',
         ]
       }]
     }
   },
     
   // Usemin
   // Replaces all assets with their revved version in html and css files.
   // options.assetDirs contains the directories for finding the assets
   // according to their relative paths
   usemin: {
     html: ['dist/*.html'],
     css: ['dist/styles/*.css'],
     options: {
       assetsDirs: ['dist', 'dist/styles']
     }
   }
   });

   grunt.registerTask('build', [
     'clean',
     'jshint',
     'useminPrepare',
     'concat',
     'cssmin',
     'uglify',
     'copy',
     'filerev',
     'usemin'
   ]);
   grunt.registerTask('default',['build']);

};
```

```html
<head>
  <title>Angular JS</title>

  <!-- build:css styles/main.css -->
  <link href="../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="../bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="styles/bootstrap-social.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="styles/mystyles.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- endbuild -->
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

your `cssmin:` is empty!

You need to do something like:

```
 cssmin: {
  target: {
    files: [{
      expand: true,
      cwd: 'release/css',
      src: ['dist/styles/*.css', '!*.min.css'],
      dest: 'release/css',
      ext: '.min.css'
    }]
  }
}
```

Take a look at: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-cssmin